# How to disable map rotation on mobile Openlayers

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers

I added `altShiftDragRotate:false` to interactions on my map but it only work in desktop mode.
when i open my page on my mobile i can rotate the map using 2 fingers.
Is there any way to disable map rotation also on mobile mode?

```
    map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Group({
                'title': 'Mapas de base',
                layers: [grisOSM, mapaOSM]
            }),
            /* new ol.layer.Group({
                title: 'Capas de información',
                layers: [ ]
            }) */

        ],
        target: 'map',
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
            zoom: true,
            attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                collapsible: false
            })
        }).extend([
            scaleLineControl
        ]),
        view: vista,
        interactions: new ol.interaction.defaults({
            altShiftDragRotate: false
        }),

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable rotation by setting `enableRotation: false` in the view object.

```
vista = new ol.View({
    ...
    enableRotation: false
})
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you